# How can I detect if Siri is writing text in textview in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitextview, siri

I have put the limit on the text view for not allowing more than 50 characters. It's not allowing to add more than 50 characters if the user writes from the keyboard. But if I add text from the voice it's going beyond the limit and its breaking boundaries.

So I don't know why it's happened...

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please show how you have put the limit for characters

Comment: you should use text field delegate for handle this.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this delegate and try again :**

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let strText = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)
    let numberOfChars = strText.characters.count 
    return numberOfChars < 50;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working , this method is not called...Thanks for your reply...

Comment: Add UITextViewDelegates on your VC class then in ViewDidLoad write textView.delegate = self

Comment: Try binding text view delegates from storyboard

Answer (score -1):

yeah got the solution

```
if (textView.text.length > 80) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(80, textView.text.length - 80);
   textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
}
```

thanks for the support

Comment: Thank you for answer.i am also looking for answer for this issue

Comment: Why do yo provide an Objective-C solution to your question which is tagged with [swift]?

Comment: And where will you apply this condition. ??

Comment: @ArpitJain  In textviewDidChnage method